# Jquery responsive slider with text block under it

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I looked a lot for a slider (jquery or bootstrap) like this [image] but I didn't find anything. So the slider has an image in top, the bullets for now many slides are and then, under it, each slide has a text block.

I tried the ones with text in top in caption, but didn't work. If someone knows any slider like in image please tell me, or if you have any idea will be great.

Comment: search here http://bootsnipp.com/search?q=carousel might help this link

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: i doubt you will get such slider ready made but with existing slider/carousel like owl carousel or bootstrap carousel you can achieve your goal. Only thing you need to add to existing carousel functionality is: add slide change event handler to know which slide is currently visible and then load the corresponding description at the bottom of slider.

Answer (score 0):

just add the following css if you are using bootstrap

```
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
.carousel-indicators li{
    border: 1px solid #f44336;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: #F44336;
}
```

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/FcFIIHGUyk)

Comment: the text from your demo is in the top of the images, I mean where the images have to be. I want that text, caption, to be under the bullets, red bullets(how you put). Is it possible?